# go error dial tcp: Protocol not available

Tags: go, tcp, http-proxy

When I tried to run GO code for rest api clint I got the error:

Get http://quotes.rest/qod.json: http: error connecting to proxy http://192.168.0.1:3128/: dial tcp 192.168.0.1:3128: i/o timeout

further I tried the same code in Go playground. There also error appeared.

What may be the reason? How can I solve this? Please help me to solve this issue.

The code I used is:-

```
package main

import(
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {

    resp, er := http.Get("http://quotes.rest/qod.json")
    if er!=nil{
            fmt.Println(er)
            return
        }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err!=nil{
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
    fmt.Println(string(content))
}
```

Comment: Your client can't connect to the proxy, is your proxy working?

Comment: The proxy is also not working

Answer (score 3):

The Go Playground does not allow HTTP requests. This has nothing to do with code. It is a security precaution enforced by the playground.