# Can't find a public file from url in go

Tags: go

I am trying to get the content of a publicly available file using `ioutil.ReadFile()` but it doesn't find the file: `panic: open http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf: No such file or directory`

Here's my code:

```
// Reading and writing files are basic tasks needed for
// many Go programs. First we'll look at some examples of
// reading files.

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

// Reading files requires checking most calls for errors.
// This helper will streamline our error checks below.
func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func main() {
    fileInUrl, err := ioutil.ReadFile("http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("HERE --- fileInUrl: %+v", fileInUrl)
}
```

Here's a go playground example

Comment: That's because a URL is not a filename.

Comment: @Flimzy It's a path to a file (noticed the .pdf in the end?), in PHP `readfile` is used to read a file from a url

Comment: @Flimzy Yeah but you're expecting me to figure out that from the function call, I'm pointing out that it's not that obvious in other languages and I didn't expect it to be obvious in go

Comment: No. I would expect you to figure that out from the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile).

Comment: Again as I wrote in my first comment, that is a path to a file. If you open it, it will download the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ioutil.ReadFile() does not support http.

If you look at the source code(https://golang.org/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go?s=1503:1549#L42), open the file using os.Open.

I think I can do this coding.

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    fileUrl := "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf"

    if err := DownloadFile("example.pdf", fileUrl); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func DownloadFile(filepath string, url string) error {

    // Get the data
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Create the file
    out, err := os.Create(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer out.Close()

    // Write the body to file
    _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
    return err
}
```

but, go playgound not protocol([go error dial tcp: Protocol not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44727653/go-error-dial-tcp-protocol-not-available)).

so, You have to do it PC.